# How to write in cell in excel using apache POI in JAVA?

Tags: java, apache-poi

How to write into excel file to the particular cell.I have a method which accepts file location and row number to which i have to write into it.

What i tried is read the file then created a cell and set the value into it, but when i look into it the cell is still blank.

```
    public void writeInExcelRowCell(String file , int rowNum) throws Exception {
        FileInputStream excelFile = new FileInputStream(new File(file));
        Workbook workbook = new XSSFWorkbook(excelFile);

        Sheet sheet = workbook.getSheetAt(0);
        sheet.getRow(rowNum).createCell(2).setCellValue("DONE");
        sheet.getRow(rowNum).createCell(3).setCellValue("PENDING");
        workbook.close();        
        
    }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you did is right, but have forgot to write your changes.
You need to open an Outputstream to write those changes.

```
    FileOutputStream outputStream = new FileOutputStream("yourfile");
    workbook.write(outputStream);
    workbook.close();
    outputStream.close();
```

Hope this works!!

Comment: Please note that you should always close resources in a `finally` block.

Comment: Yes forgot to mention that. Use finally or try-with-resources to close these stream. Thanks for that @AleksandrErokhin

Comment: @Sam i just had a question what if the cell has already some value will it override it?

Comment: Yes. I hope so.